# HTTP HEAD verb's status code

Tags: api, http, rest

According to the RFC http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the information contained in the response MAY be used to update a previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag or Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

From this definition, should we have to return `200` such as the respective GET action, of should we have to return `204` because there is no content?

Personally, I think the better interpretation would be to use `204` status code. What is your interpretation?

Comment: Seems clear enough: if your GET would return `200`, you return 200 for a `HEAD`. If your `GET` would return 204, you return 204. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the following:
the `GET` action should not return `204` because if a resource/collection exists, then a content is present.
However, given the `HEAD` content must be null, the status code would be `204`. BTW, note this _SHOULD_ term from the definition: _a HEAD request **SHOULD** be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request._ So this different status code may be the only difference between `GET` and `HEAD` headers.

Comment: Yeah the 204 intent is not in line with its title `No Content`.  IMO it's poorly titled, but I doubt I'd come up with something better.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See [Section 10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), which describes the status codes. The description of code `200` includes examples, and they include `HEAD`. So obviously they intend that the `HEAD` request should return this code.

The description of `204` explains the purpose:

> This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.